# Resize indexed PNG image with ImageMagick while preserving color map

Tags: imagemagick, png, imagemagick-convert, indexed-image

I am using custom batch script to make resized copies (33% and 66%) of all PNG images in folder. Here is my code:

```
for f in $(find /myFolder -name '*.png'); 
do
sudo cp -a $f "${f/%.png/-3x.png}"; 
sudo convert $f -resize 66.67% "${f/%.png/-2x.png}"; 
sudo convert $f -resize 33.33% $f; 
done
```

It works fine, except when the original image is indexed. In this case the smaller version of the image is RGB (so even larger file size then original image).

I have try several versions but not worked. One that I guess supposed to sort this out was fallowing:

```
for f in $(find /myFolder -name '*.png'); 
do
sudo cp -a $f "${f/%.png/-3x.png}"; 
sudo convert $f -define png:preserve-colormap -resize 66.67% "${f/%.png/-2x.png}"; 
sudo convert $f -define png:preserve-colormap -resize 33.33% $f; 
done
```

But it doesn't work.

**EDIT:**

This is updated co, but it still doesn't work as it supposed to (see the attached image-left is original, right is resized):

```
for f in $(find /myFolder -name '*.png');
do
  sudo cp -a $f "${f/%.png/-3x.png}";
  numberOfColors=`identify -format "%k" $f`

  convert "$f"                                                        \
    \( +clone -resize 66.67% -colors $numberOfColors -write "${f/%.png/-2x.png}" +delete \)  \
    -resize 33.33% -colors $numberOfColors "$f"
done
```

[image]

Original image:
[image: Original image]

Scaled version:
[image: Scaled image]

Comment: Is the issue that you want to preserve a specific, exact colourmap? Or that you want to be sure that the resized image is small and indexed to *a* colormap but you don't really mind what's in that colourmap? The answer will be different.

Comment: I don't mind the color map. I want to be sure that resized images are small. This is for retina images on web. The first (original image) is for screens with 3dpi screens and so on.

Comment: Can you provide the original images separately please - instead of joined to the output images.

Comment: How about detecting palletised images with `convert image.png -format "%[type]"  info: | grep -i Palette` and if palletised, use `-colors 250` to get the best result you can with a palletised output image.

Comment: I'm not observing this problem with the current release of ImageMagick (6.9.3-7).  Your script works fine and produces clean -2x and -3x images.  What version are you using? (use "convert | head -2" to find out).

Comment: I am using 6.8.9-9. I have tried to upgrade but with no luck. I was fallowing these instructions: http://askubuntu.com/questions/267746/how-can-i-install-the-latest-upstream-version-of-imagemagick-without-compiling

Answer (score 5):

Use "-sample" instead of "-resize" to preserve the color set.  This causes the resizing to be done by nearest-neighbor color selection rather than any kind of interpolation.

Otherwise, the colormap ends up with more than 256 colors and the png encoder can't preserve it, due to the 256-color limit on the size of a PNG PLTE chunk.  I cannot guarantee that you'll like the appearance of the result, though.

Also, be sure you are using a recent version of ImageMagick.
I'm not observing this problem with the current release (6.9.3-7). Your script works fine and produces clean -2x and -3x images.

Comment: Could OP maybe use `-resize` to get pleasing interpolation followed by `-colors 250` or `-colors 60` to allow your library to use palettised colormap?

Answer (score 0):

There are several things to address here...

**find vs glob**

You say you want to process all files in a folder, then you use `find` which will search down into sub-directories as well. If you just want to process files in the current directory, you can let `bash` do the globbing directly for you. So, instead of

```
for f in $(find . -name "*.png"); do
```

you can just do:

```
shopt -s nullglob
for f in *.png; do
```

**Performance**

You run `convert` twice and load the original image twice, and that is not very efficient. You can run a single process that loads a single image and resizes to two different sizes and writes both to disk. So, instead of

```
for ...; do
   convert ...
   convert ...
done
```

you can write the following to start one `convert`, read the image once, clone it in memory and write it out, delete the spare copy in memory and then resize the original image and re-save that.

```
for ...; do
   convert "$f"                                                        \
      \( +clone -resize 66.67% -write "${f/%.png/-2x.png}" +delete \)  \
      -resize 33.33% "$f"
done
```

**Palette**

It seems you actually only want to output palettised (indexed) images with *"any"* colormap rather than with a *"specific"* colormap. Glenn's answer is perfect if you want to retain a specific colormap. However, if any colormap is ok, you can use `-colors` to reduce the colours in the resulting image to a level where the PNG library can make the decision to create a palettised image. Glenn knows **a lot more** than me about that as he wrote it! However, I think if you reduce the colours to 250 (or so) you will probably get a 256 entry colormap and if you reduce the colours to around 60 or so, you will get a 64 entry colourmap. So, you would do:

```
shopt -s nullglob
for f in *.png; do
   sudo cp ... ...
   convert "$f"                                                        \
      \( +clone -resize 66.67% -colors 250 -write "${f/%.png/-2x.png}" +delete \)  \
      -resize 33.33% -colors 250 "$f"
done
```

You can try experimenting with other numbers of colours and see how that affects filesize - the number you need will depend on your images.

Comment: Performance is not i big issue (I am processing tens of images not thousands) but it is nice tweak. I want to process all the images in directory and sub directories so find works for me. The issue in your solution is, that I have in folder (and sub folders) a few different kinds of PNG (8-bit, 24-bit, indexed, not indexed...) so I need different parameters for different images. See my post edit for my code so far. It is not working as expected. There are large (square) areas of different color.